# Become first responder android

Tags: java, android

i would like to know if there is a corresponding class or method in android of become first responder a view like ios. My problem is that i have a scrollable Relative Layout (f1) that belongs at a scroll view (f2). When i try to scroll down the f1 , scrolls the f2.
Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You may wish to explain what "become first responder a view like ios" means.

Comment: In general, don't put scrollable views inside other scrollable views.

Comment: I mean if there is a method like this :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder
in android

Comment: Would you mind to explain what a `first responder` actually is? Possibly we know it, but associate a different name with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want a child view to receive touch events rather than a parent view. You can easily delegate touch events to child views by overriding a view's  [onTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method.

In Android, when a view returns false from it's `onTouchEvent()` method, the event is propagated down to it's child views. If this is the behavior you need, then override the `onTouchEvent()` method of the parent view and make it return false on whatever condition you desire.

Comment: This solution is very good and could work for me if I hadn't scroll views. The scroll up and scroll down listeners are implemented by the system and i cannot handle them by my self. Thank you anyway!

Comment: you can extend a scrollview and make your own scrollview where you can override the onScrollChanged() method. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10334353/1369222

Answer (score 0):

you should use onTouchEvent() and onInterceptTouchEvent():

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)