# Android AlertDialog check if scrolled to bottom

Tags: android

I intend to display an AlertDialog in Android (Android Studio) with a disclaimer message and disable the positive Button and I want to enable the button only when the user fully scrolled down to the end of the message (it is a several line long message).
I found how I can disable the button and enable it again:

disable:

```
((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                .setEnabled(false);
```

enable:

```
((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                .setEnabled(true);
```

But how can I check if the user has scrolled down to the bottom?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/a/10334353/876603?

Comment: But how can I do that? In the AlertDialog I don't have an XML? And is the message in there a ScrollView? Thanks