# Android: scrollview after scrolling get position

Tags: android, scrollview

I want get position of scrollview after scrolling

Or if scrollview at of bottom

My code :

```
final ScrollView scrMain = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrMain);
            scrMain.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}


                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // x ? y ?
                    // if scroll at bottom ?
                }
            });
```

Comment: search on google you will find solution

Comment: I search in google but not found, please send link to me. thx

Answer (score 1):

use `getViewTreeObserver()` method of your ScrollView. here is an example:

```
scrMain.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

        // horizontal scroll position
        int scrollX = scrMain.getScrollX();

        // vertical scroll position
        int scrollY = scrMain.getScrollY();
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10334353/2121682 check this then. it's quite detailed.