# How to put button on the bottom of Scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

I've tried searching all over, but I can't seem to figure this one out. Basically, I have a layout with Scrollview and elements inside it. I want to put a button inside the scrollview which would be at the end/bottom and you can only see it when you scroll all the way to the bottom.
I've tried doing it like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/topcontainer">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_review"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:title="Review Your Massage">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <include layout="@layout/card_review"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/book"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topcontainer"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The button is indeed at the bottom but there is space beneath it. If I run the app on a phone with bigger resolution, the button will be almost in the middle of the screen. How can I make it so no matter the resolution it will always stay on bottom?

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like at the moment:[image]

Comment: remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: set Height of ScrollView = "match_parent" & not "wrap_content"
same for RelativeLayout

Comment: and add Button below <include layout="@layout/card_review"/>. Remove Relative layout

Comment: 1. Removed android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and added the button below <include layout="@layout/card_review"/>. Also removed the Relative Layout. I still get the same result.

2. I set Height of ScrollView = "match_parent" and I do the same for Relative Layout. I still get the same result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:fillViewport="true"` the `ScrollView` uses all the available space, even if the children are smaller.

The `Space` has a `android:layout_weight="1"` to receive the extra space, so the button is always at the bottom.

An [explanation by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) with more details.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/topcontainer">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_review"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:title="Review Your Massage">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <include layout="@layout/card_review"/>

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonReview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="@string/book" />
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but when I do it your way, the button disappears.

Comment: for both cases ? (with a content smaller / bigger than the screen)

Comment: What happen if you replace the include part with a simple `View` having a fixed height ?

Comment: I finally made it! Instead of using the `<include layout="@layout/card_review"/>`, I put the whole CardView and added the Space widget with the button below it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/topcontainer">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_review"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:title="Review Your Massage">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <include layout="@layout/card_review"/>

</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="@string/book"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If I use this on lets say Nexus 6P, it works, the button is on bottom. But, if I use it on Nexus 4, the content is not scrollable and the button is always shown. I need it to be shown only when you scroll down to it.

Comment: You can try, hiding the button and making it visible when the scrollView reaches the bottom. heres a link which explains how to detect when scrollView hits the bottom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316743/detect-end-of-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in scrollview and height should be match_parent.

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```